# Laravel: what is the difference of Redirect::to and redirect()?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-named-routes) I always see `redirect()` but whenever I try to find solutions some users refer to `Route::to()` or `Route::route()` I have 2 questions:

1. What is the difference between the two?
2. Is the `redirect()` the most updated usage and the preferred method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redirect()` is a global helper function, provided by `Illuminate\Foundation` that is accessing the same binding, `redirect`, as the facade (`Redirect`) does.

These should be equivalents:

```
Redirect::to('home');
redirect('home');
redirect()->to('home');

Redirect::route('someroute');
redirect()->route('someroute');
```

For part 2 of the question, without going into certain concerns (and avoiding others), one could potentially consider it a preference at the moment. The facades exist and there are also helper functions for some things. The helpers were added more recently but they are just another way to resolve the same underlying bindings and act on them.

Comment: So which of the 2 do you think I should use in practice?

Comment: I'm using `Redirect::route` which is my preference as of the moment, as it is easy to remind myself that it is a `facade`. Many thanks!